# Can I create a Run Configuration in Eclipse without specifying main class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple Java projects in Eclipse, which I would like to sometimes run with some arguments (same args for every project). Therefore I would like to create a Run Configuration which I would run on chosen project. Creating a RC for every project is a little too much hassle for me. Ideal solution for me is that I could click on a project or main class, select my run configuration and I'd run this project with specified arguments. Or maybe somebody could come up with some clever and usable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few quirks, but it is doable.

**Main**

- Project must be specified explicitly, but it is not that relevant for your use case.
- Use ${java_type_name} as Main class name.

**JRE**

- Select an appropriate JRE

**Classpath**

- Make sure the JRE is selected in Bootstrap Entries
- User entries must contain a variable string ${project_classpath}